# Как различить устройства на одном IP адресе?

Tags: c++, сеть, сокет, qtnetwork

Меня интересует проблема как различать устройства в одной подсети для создания сокет соединения.
Допустим имеется имеется обычный телефон с которого я раздаю wifi и интернет. К нему подключены 2 устройства на которых открыты Слушающие сокеты.
Программно я могу получить на каждом из устройств локальный IP и порта, пусть это будет к примеру:

192.168.0.1 / 1111

192.168.0.2 / 2222

И отослать их на свой сервер в сети. Сервер составит таблицу из "Серого IP" каждого из устройств и IP\порт подсети. т.е.

1. ххх.ххх.ххх.хх1 / 192.168.0.1 / 1111
2. ххх.ххх.ххх.хх1 / 192.168.0.2 / 2222

Так же у нас имеется третье устройство, которое находится удаленно по другому адресу:

3. ххх.ххх.ххх.хх2 / 192.168.0.1 / 1111

По факту я хотел бы установить прямое сокет соединение между 3-им и\или 1-ым и 2-ым устройством. Но т.к. устроства 2 и 1 находятся на одном IP адресе и кроме порта их ничего не различает, у меня вопрос: как установить соединение с такими сокетами, которые висят на одном IP адресе с другого устройства? Тем более порты могут и совпадать иногда.

Comment: ххх.ххх.ххх.хх1 и ххх.ххх.ххх.хх2 различаются же

Comment: «устроства 2 и 1 находятся на одном IP адресе» — в вашем примере у них опять же различаются 192.168.0.1 и 192.168.0.2, так что не очень понятно в чём у вас собственно проблема

Comment: В общем случае, если между вами и интересующим вас устройством стоит NAT, который прячет от вас IP и порт устройства, то установить с ним соединение невозможно вообще никак. Если вы имеете внешний IP-адрес без NAT, то такое устройство может подключиться к вам, но не вы к нему

Comment: Если все трое устройств спрятаны за NAT, то соединить их друг с другом напрямую никак. В реальной жизни обычно настраивают проброс порта от внутреннего IP на внешний IP где-то в настройках роутера, чтобы можно было обойти NAT через этот самый проброшенный порт. Однако если NAT провайдерский и неподконтрольный, то тут уже ничего не сделать

Comment: Если более быть точным, то два участника торрент сети в локалке, раздают третьему-удаленному файл. Такое возможно?

Comment: Ну или допустим телега на 2-ух устройствах десктоп и мобайл на одном IP работают, и так же декстоп и мобайл на другом IP. Они SIP между собой могут как-то напрямую осуществлять или обязательно через сервер коннектиться?

Comment: Программа может попытаться пробить NAT через какой-нибудь [UDP hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching). Если получится и программа добудет себе UDP-порт, доступный извне, — можно использовать его для прямого соединения. Если не получится, то единственный способ это передавать все данные через какой-то сторонний сервер. Ну и это не работает с TCP (и с UDP тоже работает далеко не всегда)

Comment: на двух серверах закажите ipv6 разные адреса. И все клиенты в обеих сетях могут друг друга видеть. https://tunnelbroker.net/

Comment: @AlexGlebe tunnelbroker это по сути и есть один из вариантов стороннего сервера

Comment: можно ещё без брокеров воспользоваться SSH туннелями. [Практические советы, примеры и туннели SSH](https://habr.com/ru/articles/435546/)

Comment: @andreymal, так у него вроде все устройства будут в рамках одного ната и выходить за его пределы для связи между ними не надо. Или я неправильно понял что-то?

Answer (score 0):

Изходя из вопроса - ответ что никак, это связано с пробросом портов наружу, а такое невозможно на чужеродных сетевых роутерах.